# what does the concept of using dot product and < do in the following code?

Tags: c++

```
bool operator() (const Vertex& a, const Vertex& b) const
    {
        return dot(a,dir)<dot(b,dir); 
    }
```

The dot() returns the dot product of a,dir.what is the use of < symbol in  above program code?

Comment: Please study the absolute basics of a programming language before trying to write code in it.

Comment: less than.  It's one of the six basic comparison operators in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza In my experience, beginners are stunned by the fact that you can write arbitrary epressions after the `return` keyword, not just literals like `42` and variables like `x`. midhun probably parsed the statement as `(return dot(a,dir)) < dot(b, dir);` and got utterly confused what it means to compare a return statement like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both vectors are normalized (i.e. their lengths equal 1) the dot product returns the cosine of the angle between them (range is -1..+1). So the operator effectively returns whether the vector of the first vertex has a larger angle to the direction vector than the vector of the second vertex.

Answer (score 2):

```
return condition;
```

is just shorthand for

```
if (condition)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

For some reason, beginners tend to find the second version easier to understand.